# MyBatis:collection via annotation in one query

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

I have an xml mapper - one select and one result mapper. It works without problems. But I want to use annotations. My mapper:

```
  <resultMap id="readItemsRM" type="com.company.Item">
   <id property="id" column="Id"/>
    <result property="comment" column="Comment"/>
    <collection property="textItems" ofType="com.company.TextItem">
        <id property="id" column="TxId"/>
        <result property="name" column="TxName"/>
      </collection>
    </resultMap>
```

So I did like this

```
   @Results({
        @Result(id=true, property="id", column="Id"),
        @Result(property="comment", column="Comment"),
        ///,???        
    })
   public List<Item> select();
```

I can't understand how can I map my collection via annotation without executing one more sql query. As all the examples I found suppose executing one more query. Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot use `JOIN`s if you are using mapping with annotations.

From the [doc](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/java-api.html), about the usage of `@Many`,

> A mapping to a collection property of a complex type. Attributes:
>   select, which is the fully qualified name of a mapped statement (i.e.
>   mapper method) that can load a collection of instances of the
>   appropriate types, fetchType, which supersedes the global
>   configuration parameter lazyLoadingEnabled for this mapping. **NOTE
>   You will notice that join mapping is not supported via the Annotations
>   API. This is due to the limitation in Java Annotations that does not
>   allow for circular references.**

You can directly use your ResultMap with annotations if you like:

```
@Select("SELECT QUERY")
@ResultMap("readItemsRM")
public List<Item> select();
```

Answer (score 3):

I found out that you can actually do one-to-many or one-to-one joins using Java annotations on MyBatis

```
public class Master {
    private String nama;
    private Short usia;
    private List<Contoh> contohs;
}

public interface MasterMapper {

    @Select("SELECT master.nama, master.usia FROM test.master WHERE master.nama = #{nama}")
    @Results(value = {
         @Result(property="nama", column="nama"),
         @Result(property="usia", column="usia"),
         @Result(property="contohs", javaType=List.class, column="nama", 
         many=@Many(select="getContohs"))
    })
    Master selectUsingAnnotations(String nama);

    @Select("SELECT contoh.id, contoh.nama, contoh.alamat "
         + " FROM test.contoh WHERE contoh.nama = #{nama}")
    List<Contoh> getContohs(String nama);
}
```

There are more details in this [link](http://edwin.baculsoft.com/2010/12/beginning-mybatis-3-part-2-how-to-handle-one-to-many-and-one-to-one-selects/)

Comment: @JinKwon what issue are you having exactly?

Comment: I think this will cause N+1 problem.

Comment: This will probably lead to 1 + 1. It will call getContohs once. Still strange though

Comment: This _will_ cause N+1 problem, `@Many` is exactly for this. The `getConhots` will be cause once for each row from the `selectUsingAnnotations` query

Answer (score 0):

Inner join queries using ibatis annoation's Example.

```
@Select("SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2, t2.column3, t2.column4 "
            + "FROM table1 AS t1 "
            + "INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 "
            + "ON (t1.column1 = t2.column3)  WHERE t1.column1=#{id}")
    @Results(value = {
            @Result(property = "val1", column = "column1"),
            @Result(property = "val2", column = "column2"),
            @Result(property = "val3", column = "column3"),
            @Result(property = "val4", column = "column4")})
    MyBean getInnerJoinResult(@Param("id") Integer id);
```

Answer (score -1):

I have worked for me, cheking the link that @feco but my structure of the table is a little bit different, so the mapping in the example was from master table to list, let's check the code.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS item_service (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  description varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  service_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk1_item_service_service FOREIGN KEY (service_id) REFERENCES service (id),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS service (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


package com.****;

import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "item_service")
public class Item {

    /*
        Each item has a service linked to the Service class.
        Each Service is not mandatory has items. But, the service could have many items asociated. it depends the JPA Aproach that you have.
        */ 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false) //could be redundant, doesn matter for the example
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "description"),
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "service_id", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Service service;

    /*getters and setters*/
}

package com.***;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "item_service")
public class Service {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;
    /*getters and setter*/

}

@Mapper
public interface ItemServiceMapper {

    @Select("SELECT * FROM item_service")
    @Results(value = {
            @Result(column = "service_id", property = "service", javaType = Service.class, one = @One(select = "getService")),
            @Result(column = "receipt_id", property = "receipt", javaType = Receipt.class, one = @One(select = "getReceipt")),
    })
    List<ItemService> findAllall();

    @Select("SELECT * FROM service WHERE id= #{id}")
    Service getService(@Param("id") Long id);

    @Select("SELECT * FROM service WHERE id= #{id}")
    Receipt getReceipt(@Param("id") Long id)
}
```